# closed set in A meaning

Tags: general-topology

When books say that A is a closed subset of B, which is itself a subset of some topological space, does this mean A is closed in the subspace topology on B, or does it mean A is closed in the 'parent' space and contained in B?

Thanks

Comment: Hopefully it's possible to work this out from context, as it seems ambiguous to me also. They are certainly not equivalent for instance if $B=(0,1)\subset\mathbb{R}$ and $A=B$, then $A$ is a closed subset of $B$ under the former interpretation but not the latter.

Comment: I think that in most cases the book itself will be clear on that by its context. Normally, if there is no context then '$A$ is closed in $B$' refers to the first meaning. The expression '$A$ is a closed subset of $B$' is less common.

Comment: @Daniel Rust Another example is 'let A c B be open'. I've always taken that to mean A is open in the 'parent' topology. What say you? By 'c' I mean contained in by the way.

Comment: Well, in a similar way, the context will determine the interpretation, as $A=[0,1]$ is open in $B=[0,1]$ with the subspace topology on $B$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ but it is not open in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

One implies the other: if $A \subset B \subset X$ and $A$ is closed in $X$, then as $A \cap B = A$, by the definition of the subspace topology of $B$, $A$ is closed in $B$ as well.

But personally, if I read that $A$ is closed in $B$, I would assume it meant that $A$ is closed in the subspace topology of $B$. A good author would make it clear from the context, IMHO.